# Simplifying Array Access

Tags: lean, lean4

I'm confused how to show the second `example` here:

```lean
example (n:Nat): [n][0] = n := 
by
  simp

example (n:Nat): #[n][0] = n := 
by
  sorry
```

I tried a few different ways without success.  The first is fine since we're using a `List` rather than an `Array`.  *What did I miss?*

Comment: > The Lean type checker has no special support for reducing Arrays. from https://lean-lang.org/lean4/doc/array.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get when writing that example should guide you in understanding how to solve your issue:

```haskell
failed to prove index is valid, possible solutions:
  - Use `have`-expressions to prove the index is valid
  - Use `a[i]!` notation instead, runtime check is perfomed, and 'Panic' error message is produced if index is not valid
  - Use `a[i]?` notation instead, result is an `Option` type
  - Use `a[i]'h` notation instead, where `h` is a proof that index is valid
n: Nat
⊢ 0 < Array.size #[n]
```

You have 3 possible options here:

- if you use the `a[i]!` notation, you won't be able to prove your theorem since lean won't reduce this. This won't work.
- you may use `a[i]?` to prove that `#[n][0]? = some n` instead
- additionally, you could provide a proof that your 0 index is a valid index in this case.

In practice, the best way to do this would be to teach Lean that your index is indeed correct. You can do so by providing `simp` lemmas for this.
The following code works:

```haskell
-- Works without adding a lemma
example (n:Nat): #[n][0]? = some n := rfl

-- We can manually provide a proof that `0 < #[n].size` 
example (n:Nat): #[n][0]'(Nat.lt_succ_self 0) = n := rfl

-- Alternatively, we can provide that proof to `simp` by tagging the theorem as such
@[simp]
theorem zero_lt_array_one : 0 < #[a].size := Nat.lt_succ_self 0

-- No need to provide a proof now, it just works !
example (n:Nat): #[n][0] = n := rfl
```

Alternatively, you could just import the standard library, which provides everything lean needs to know such array access is well-behaved:

```haskell
import Std

example (n:Nat): #[n][0] = n := rfl
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Lean 4 is intended to not reduce `Array`-related stuffs:

> The Lean type checker has no special support for reducing Arrays.

From: https://lean-lang.org/lean4/doc/array.html

By some analysis, we can see that Lean refuses to calculate the size of `#[n]`:

```
example (n: Nat):
  let x := #[n];
  let ix : Fin x.size := 0;
  x[ix] = n :=
by
  sorry
```

The definition `ix` also raises error, but it makes the following code type check.

However, you can postulate a proof that `0 < x.size`:

```
example (n: Nat):
  let x := #[n];
  let h : 0 < x.size := by sorry;
  x[0] = n :=
by
  trivial
```

Comment: I don't understand ... so what, basically we can't use arrays ??

Comment: @redjamjar: You can use arrays, but only in safe ways.

Comment: @redjamjar you can write programs with arrays, but you can't reason about them.

Comment: @ice1000: Would you really say that? If you provide proofs of correctness of indices, as you should, you *can* reason about arrays.

Comment: @AndrejBauer you're right. I should say you can't reason about them as naturally as you could reason about lists -- you would pay extra effort to do so.